# Comparing arrays of different sizes in numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am working on a knowledgebase in which I want to compare the distinct rows of coordinates if they are a subset of one another. If yes a right outer join should be applied on the larger array.
Example

```
knowledgebase = [
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],
[[1,2],[5,6]]
]
```

The nested pair of values are coordinates [[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...]...]. While the coordinate pairs themself do not have an order the two values within have. X is always first here. I already tried to utilize sets but those don't work since one can not make a set of lists. I implemented a solution in plain python.

```
for element1 in knowledgebase:
    for element2 in knowledgebase:
        if element1 == element2:
            continue
        if all(x in element2 for x in element1):
            outer_join = [item for item in element2 if item not in element1]
            if outer_join not in knowledgebase:
                knowledgebase.append(outer_join)
```

However this approach is to slow because of the nested for loops so I wondered if there is something similar in Numpy.

I defined a numpy array like this.

```
knowledgebase = np.array([
list([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], dtype=object),
list([[1,2],[5,6]], dtype=object)
])
```

and would like to apply the algorithm above to it, but I am not sure how to do it in an efficient way. Also maybe my approach of nesting the python lists inside of the array is not the best approach, but I couldn't figure out how to create a numpy array with different lengts of rows.

Comment: `knowledgebase` is not valid python, and wouldn't be valid numpy. Please provide clear reproducible inputs

Comment: Sorry I forgot the brackets. It is executable now.

Comment: I am pretty sure you meant `if element1==element2: continue`. With `break` you test only half of the cases. Which could be a good idea if the test was symetric, but it is not here.

Comment: Good point. I'll adapt the example

Answer (score 1):

You should really take a moment to reconsider your choice of data structures. Why are you initially storing it as a list? Are the different coordinates ordered? Is the row `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` supposed to be different from `[[5,6],[1,2],[3,4]]` ?

If as I expect it is not the case, you should consider using more appropriate data structures. The first idea which comes to mind is sets since you're trying to work with intersections.
With sets, your example becomes:

```
#permutations will allow us to loop over pairs of distinct elements,
#eliminating the need for the element1==element2  test
from itertools import permutations

knowledgebase = set([
    frozenset([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]),
    frozenset([(1,2),(5,6)])
    ])
new_knowledge = set()
for element1, element2 in permutations(knowledgebase, 2):
        if element1.issubset(element2):
                diff = element2.difference(element1)
                new_knowledge.add(diff)
knowledgebase = knowledgebase.union(new_knowledge)
```

The reason we use `frozenset` for the rows is that these sets are elements of  the set `knowledgebase` so they need to be immutable. Similarly this is why we have to use tuples for coordinates instead of lists. Finally, I used `new_knowledge` as a temporary sink for all the new rows because adding new elements to an object we're currently looping over is a recipe for disaster and unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The nested pair of values are coordinates [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...]. While the coordinate pairs themself do not have an order the two values within have. X is always first here. I already tried to utilize sets but those don't work since one can not make a set of lists. e.g. ([x1,y1],[x2,y2]) is not possible, since lists are not hashable. Sorry for the confusion. I updated my post.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to be using a list  [x,y] instead of a tuple (x,y) ? If so using a tuple as I did in the answer solves this as tuples are immutable and thus hashable.
The key to performance gains here is in using hashable objects wherever you can